# seState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

In my app component below I want to hide a div based on a function I have defined but it brings an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Please what may be wrong

```
class Apps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Don't do this!
        this.state = { showing: true };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <div className="container">
                <div style={{ display: (this.state.showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
                     A Single Page web application made with react
                 </div>
             </div>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <a href='' onClick={this.onclick} >Login</a>
                    <br/>
                    <a href='' >Signup</a>
                    <br />
                    <a href='' >Members</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onclick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({showing: false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. `bind` the function to `this` in the render method so that `this` will be what you expect in your `onclick` method. You can read more about why this is the case [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

```
<a href='' onClick={this.onclick.bind(this)}>Login</a>
```

Comment: If i don't bind it, what will the this be expecting

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene If you don't bind it, the value of `this` will be the global object which is `window` in the browser, so it will not work as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bind or you can just use an arrow ES6 function instead of binding it

```
 onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showing: false });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tholle is right. You have to bind your onclick function to current class instance using **this**. By default this here points to global window obj, which does not have setState function.

1. Either you bind your function to **this**, where you are calling it as tholle suggests.
2. You can also bind it to this in constructor after calling super(props):

   this.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this);
3. **this** can also be bound implicitly using arrow function like this:

   < a href="" onClick={e=>this.onclick(e)} ... ./>

Best practice is to use 2nd option. As using 1st and 3rd options will create new references for the functions each time component renders. However, that's ok to use 1st or 3rd option if you have no problem with memory consumption or creating a small app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 arrow functions to bind lexical this:

**href='' onClick= {(e) => this.onclick(e)}**